# Meteor: Passing more than one value to a template

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I want to create a template/js combo similar to the ones below. What I would like is to have two variables available to the 'collection' template

```html
<template name="collection">
  Title: {{title}}
  <UL>
  {{#each items}}
    {{> item}}
  {{/each}}
  </UL>
</template>

<template name="collection_items"> 
  <LI>{{item_title}}</LI>
</template>
```

Where the javascript function would be something like:

```js
Template.collection.data = function() {
  var record = Record.findOne({whatever:value});
  return { title: record.title, items: record.items }
}
```

I've tried using Handlebars' {{#with data}} helper and return an object as above, but that just crashed the template. I've tried creating a 'top level' function like:

```js
Template.collection = function () {... }
```

but that also crashed the template.

What I'm trying to avoid is having two separate functions (one Template.collection.title, and one Template collection.items) where each of them calls a findOne on the Record collection where really its the same template and one call should suffice.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not return the record itself? I believe you can also use `{{something.something}}`

Comment: That's what I thought too but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not only it doesn't work, if I put {{record.field_a}} and {{record.field_b}} it calls the 'record' function twice, defeating the purpose of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Well, {{#with something}} should work, I don't see why it wouldn't. Take a look at the todos example, I'm pretty sure #with is used there in the way you want it to be used...

Comment: Actually, #with is not in the todos example... And no, it doesn't work . I wouldn't be asking this if it was in todos example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
Template.collection = function () {... }
```

Template.collection is not a function, it's an instance and thus an object.

You can type `Template.collection` in the console to see something essential as well as `Template.collection.` and autocomplete that to see its methods and fields.

---

For a #with example, the Todos indeed doen't seem to contain one as you have outlined in your comments. So, an example use of it can be found here:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/templating/templating_tests.js#L75
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/templating/templating_tests.html#L92

Here is another example that I tried that works on both the current master and devel branch:

```html
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  {{#with author}}
  <h2>By {{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h2>
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

And the JS part of it:

```js
if (Meteor.is_client) {
  Template.hello.author = function () {
    return {
      firstName: "Charles",
      lastName: "Jolley"
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason why you're hoping to avoid two functions?

From your code sample I see one issue: the first template is calling a second template with this line:

```
{{> item}}
```

But your second template is not called 'items'. I believe that your second template should be called this way:

```
<template name="item">
```

Seems that it would be simple enough to have helper functions for the first and the second. Although I haven't gotten it to work with my own code, I believe the second helper function would want to use the 'this' convention to refer to the collection you're referring to.

Cheers -  holling

Comment: Yes the template naming is a typo there. Should've been collection_item. In any case, two functions mean two calls to mongo to load up the record. The item list is an array of the item. My problem turned out to be a stupid misunderstanding of reactivity on my part (i'll post the reason in a sec)

Answer (score 0):

Tom's answer is correct. I want to just chime in and add that in my scenario the reason why #with was failing was because due to the 'reactive' nature of meteor my first call to load the model resulted in 'undefined' and I didn't check for it. A fraction later it was loaded ok. 
The moral is to do something like

```
var record = Record.findOne({whatever:value})
if (record) {
  return record;
} else {
  // whatever
  return "loading"
}
```